# Jest Enzyme test case coverage

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Need help on writing the test case for below function using jest and enzyme...  The asView below is a function that returns a view for my case ...

```
showRowSubView = (rowModel) => {
    if (rowModel.has('tiers')) {
      const record = rowModel.toJSON();
      /* eslint-disable react/no-danger */
      const template = asView(() =>
        record.tiers.map(item => (
          <table >
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div className="tiersTable" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.returnTemplate(item)} />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        )),
      );
      return template;
    }
    return null;
  };
```

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
const model = {
 tiers:['a','b','c']
};

it('showRowSubView',()=>{
 const wrapper = shallow(<ShowRowSubView rowModel={model }/>);
 expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```